# How to transition from M2M created with 'through' to a M2M managed by Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working in a Project where there were multiple fields created as M2M using the `through` related model, however they were wrongly created by then and the related models have no additional fields, so I would like to use a regular M2M managed by Django.

The existing models I have are:

```py
cass Student(models.Model):
    # ... other fields..."
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(
        Course,
        related_name='students',
        through='StudentCourse'
    )

class StudentCourse(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

cass Course(models.Model):
    # ... other fields..."
```

And I would like to have:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    # ... other fields..."
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='students')

class Course(models.Model):
    # ... other fields..."
```

I'm not able to find a way in Django to do this without losing the data that was already inserted.

I was thinking of renaming the tables in the same way Django does and manipulate the Django migration metadata but it is an ugly way to solve it.

Is there a Django way to solve this without losing the data (or creating backup tables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to create a migration file that copies the data from the old through table to the new one.

First create an empty migration file that will be populated with our migration operations

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app> --empty
```

Then that migration needs to be populated with the following (`<app>` should be replaced with the app name of the app)

```
from django.db import migrations, models


def move_courses(apps, schema_editor):
    Student = apps.get_model('<app>', 'Student')
    StudentCourse = apps.get_model('<app>', 'StudentCourse')
    for student in Student.objects.all():
        student.courses.set(
            StudentCourse.objects.filter(student=student).values_list('course', flat=True)
        )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('<app>', '<XXXX_previous_migration_name>'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # Remove the old ManyToManyField
        # This won't delete the through table or it's data
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='Student',
            name='courses',
        ),
        # Add the new ManyToManyField
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='Student',
            name='courses',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='students', to='<app>.Course'),
        ),
        # Run a script that copies data from the old through table to the new one
        migrations.RunPython(move_courses),
        # Delete the old through table
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='StudentCourse',
        ),
    ]
```

Then update your models in the way you like:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    # ... other fields..."
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(
        Course,
        related_name='students',
    )

# Since through='StudentCourse' was removed, below is removed to (keeping it as comment to represent the removal)
# class StudentCourse(models.Model):
#    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Course(models.Model):
    # ... other fields..."
```

After models and the empty created migration is updated, you can run `migrate`

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Important: don't run `makemigrations` again, only `migrate` in order for Django to run the migration that moves the data.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza let me know if you have any trouble, this should work although some DBs may not behave well

Comment: What about the original model? Besides this migration I'd need to modify the existing models and remove the old StudentCourse related model, will Django address the conflict between migrations?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza if you change your models to be like your "like to have" section and delete the StudentCourse model, with this migration everything should be fine. The migration copies the data from the StudentCourse model to the new through model/table before deleting the StudentCourse table

Comment: I'm getting this error
`ValueError: The field app.Student.courses was declared with a lazy reference to 'app.courses', but app 'app' doesn't provide model 'course'.`, any idea?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza in the migration? Did you replace all instances of `<app>` with the name of your app in the migration? Shouldn't it be `app.Course` capitalized?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing but no luck

Comment: The model is named "Course" right? Think you may have a trailing "s" that shouldn't be there: `app.Course` not `app.Courses`

Comment: I've missed an `s` in the question (just added), it's `<app>.models.Student.courses`. I'm executing the `makemigration` that is generating that error, should I first run the `migrate` and then `makemigration` after updating the models as I "like to have"?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza First thing is to run `makemigrations <app> --empty` and then edit that migration to contain the operations above. Then edit your models. Then `migrate` to migrate all the data

Comment: Awesome Iain, I finally made it work. I updated your answer with the information, there were little case mismatch and also I was running `makemigrations` again before `migrate` that was generating conflicts.